# Laravel Collections - compare and check how many times a word exits in a collection

Tags: php, laravel

i am new to Laravel and i am trying to do the following:
i have 2 Collections: "requirements" and "skills":

```
$req = collect([
    'Installation',
    'Konfiguration',
    'Automatisierung' 
]);

$skills = collect([
    'Engineering Team',
    'Installation',
    'Konfiguration',
    'Konfiguration',
    'Automatisierung',
    'Security',
    'Automatisierung',
    'Automatisierung',
    'Automatisierung'
]);
```

I am trying the following: I want to take the first item of $req ("Installation") and count how many times it  exists in the  $skills collection. Then i need to take the second value of the $req collection and do the same thing. At the end i need to have some output like:

Installation exits 2 times
Konfiguration exists 2 times
Automatisierung exists 3 times
all others -> 0 (or even ignoring it)

i thought about iterating with nested for loops and if clauses and so on like "classic" coding, but isnt there something in laravel to make it nicer? I tried like contains and so on but its like "if" clause.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Not sure about Laravel, but PHP has a helpful method: [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values).

Comment: P.S. How is PHPStorm related to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use countBy of laravel, it counts depending on a function

[Learn more about countBy here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-countBy)

This code would return another array with the 3 sentences you've said

```php
$req->map(function($i) use ($skills) {
    $count = $skills->countBy(function ($skill) use ($i) {
        return $skill == $i;
    });

    if (isset($count[1])) {
        return $i . " exits ". $count[1] ." times";
    } else {
        return $i . " doesn't exits";
    }
});
```

You can also just do `$skills->countBy()` that it would return an collection with key beeing the name of the skill and the value beeing the number of times it appears

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend.

Comment: Hi again, can you please explain your solutin a litte bit. It does work but am trying to apply it to another  2 collections which where created by 1. Applying "explode" method to create an array by a string. Secondly create an empty collection and then added the array to it by "union" method. This was done to 2 sentence to create 2 Collections. When then tryting to apply your solution to these 2 collections it gives me an error : "Undefined offset: 1" Its beause of $count[1] , But why is that? I still have 2 Collections. i am confused.

Comment: @Rabik oooh yeah, probably a mistake of my code, I think that the word that it is looking on the look doesnt exists on the other collection so the $count variable doest have the second index where it should be the count for the word

Comment: countBy returns an array with all the counted words, if you had done `$skills->countBy` it would count every repeated word and created a collection with key => value the key beeing the word and the value beeing the number of times it appears on the collection

Comment: Since we are specifying the word on `$skill == $i` it just test if that skill is on the collection and the array it returns is usually with 2 items, the first one is the number of items that didnt passed on `$skill == $i` and the second one is the number of items that have passed, but since the skill might doesnt exists, the second item from the array can never exists

Comment: Hi, the thing is, that your code works perfectly fine when i manually create 2 Collections like in the Question, but when i create it the way it described it in my comment it gives me this error. I compared the 2 diffrently created Collections by printing the entries. They are again the same. i counted them: Same. the structure shold also be the same i guess. But your code works for one pair of collections but not the other.

Comment: SO HERE IS THE SOLUTION, you have do to a test `if(isset($count[1])` before return thar sentence, and than an else code where you return another sentence, maybe `$i . " doesn't exits";`

Comment: @Rabik yeah, I can se the other example if you create the question an help you better

Comment: Ill create another question. Thanks man. Appreciate.

Comment: Hey Bro, your solution with if (isset($count[1])) worked fine. :D hahaah.. i am happy now. I thank you very much man.